# Magento 2 : Delete address from after login from address book

Tags: magento2, customer-account, magento2.2, address

I want to delete the address which I have saved earlier from here but in **vendor-> Magento_Customer\templates\address** in addressbook file we have only edit address action but not delete action so please help me any help will be appreciated.

Here is the code for delete anchor tag->

```
    <div class="item actions">
       <a class="action edit" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getUrl('customer/address/edit', ['id' => $_address->getId()]) ?>"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Edit Address') ?></span></a><a class="action delete" href="#" role="delete-address" data-address="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_address->getId() ?>"><span><?php /* ## Heading ##@escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Delete Address') ?></span></a>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because Magento allows deleting the address when having one more addresses. We can add one more address and will see the delete button.

If we're really want to delete the address, we can base on the script:

**vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/address/book.phtml**

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        ".page-main": {
            "address": {
                "deleteAddress": "li.item a[role='delete-address']",
                "deleteUrlPrefix": "<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeUrl($block->getDeleteUrl())) ?>id/",
                "addAddress": "button[role='add-address']",
                "addAddressLocation": "<?= $block->escapeJs($block->escapeUrl($block->getAddAddressUrl())) ?>"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

---

**[EDIT]**

We can add the delete button:

```
<form action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getUrl('customer/address/delete', ['id' => $_pAddsses])) ?>">
    <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
    <button type="submit" class="action delete">
        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Delete Address')) ?></span>
    </button>
</form>
```

`$_pAddsses` is the id of address.

We need to add the form key to form because `vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Address/Delete.php` will check.

Comment: after adding this script  what should i add in the href="?" section of delete anchor tag

Comment: `"deleteAddress": "li.item a[role='delete-address']",` it's the element selection. Do you want to re-use the js?

Comment: i would prefer like above edit button so delete directly by taking address Id

Comment: I will check and let you know.

Comment: @sourabhyadav I updated my answer.

Comment: Hi@Khoa TruongDinh, after deleting the address and how to save the address id

Comment: @DileepKumar could you explain more details or can you ask new question?

Comment: Hi@Khoa TruongDinh, please check the screenshot

Comment: Hi@Khoa TruongDinh, prnt.sc/rpy0pr
I click the delete and it will be deleted successfully and I need to save the address id
How to save address ID?
Please help me?

Comment: Hi@Khoa TroungDinh, Please check my screenshot https://prnt.sc/rqm1dh

Comment: Hi@KhoaTruongDinh, I want to save only deleting address Id? Please help me?

Comment: did you try `beforeSave` plugin? @DileepKumar

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh, Please help me?  I don't know plugin concept.

Comment: @DileepKumar could you please create a new question?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh Thanks!. It works for me.